# SQL query in stored procedure to update one table from another based on few calculations?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, insert, cursor

I am trying to create records from one table (MasterData) and insert new (multiple records) into another table (Orders) in MS SQL Server.

Initially I have been thinking of using cursors (in a stored procedure) but I am a bit unsure whether it is possible just to use a select into statement?

I have added some code for generating the two tables (the input table = MasterData and the output table = Orders). Additionally, I have added a couple of sample data records in the input table.

```
CREATE TABLE MasterData (
  ItemId VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
  ItemDescription VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  Minimum INT NOT NULL,
  ROP INT NOT NULL,
  Maximum INT NOT NULL,
  Multiple INT NOT NULL,
  InventoryPosition INT NOT NULL,
  [Location] VARCHAR(30),

);

INSERT INTO MasterData (ItemId, ItemDescription, Minimum, ROP, Maximum, Multiple, InventoryPosition, Location)
VALUES ('Item001', 'Item Description 001', 10, 15, 40, 5, 16, 'DC01'),
 ('Item002', 'Item Description 002', 20, 30, 50, 10, 29, 'DC02'),
 ('Item003', 'Item Description 003', 30, 33, 50, 0, 10, 'DC01');

 CREATE TABLE Orders (
  ItemId VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
  ItemDescription VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  InventoryStart INT NOT NULL,
  InventoryEnd INT NOT NULL,
  Quantity INT NOT NULL,
  Location VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  Classification VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,);
```

The output that the stored procedure should generate into table "Orders" would be the following result:

```
INSERT INTO Orders (ItemId, ItemDescription, InventoryStart, InventoryEnd, Quantity, Location, Classification)
VALUES ('Item002', 'Item Description 001', 29, 39, 10, 'DC02', 'Under ROP'),
 ('Item002', 'Item Description 002', 39, 49, 10, 'DC02', 'Under Max'),
 ('Item002', 'Item Description 002', 49, 59, 10, 'DC02', 'Above Max'),
 ('Item003', 'Item Description 003', 10, 20, 10, 'DC01', 'Under Min'),
 ('Item003', 'Item Description 003', 20, 33, 13, 'DC01', 'Under ROP'),
 ('Item003', 'Item Description 003', 33, 50, 17, 'DC01', 'Under Max');
```

The algorithm that should be applied has the following flow:

1. If a record in MasterData has an 'InventoryPosition' value lower than 'ROP' new records should be created in table: Orders. Else the record in MasterData should be skipped and the logic should iterate to next record.
2. If the above is true, new records should be created until InventoryEnd is above Maximum.
3. InventoryStart is for the first record in the Orders table (within the ItemId) equal to InventoryPosition from MasterData. InventoryEnd would be equal to InventoryStart + Multiple. From hereon InventoryStart (on record 2 and higher) would be equal to InventoryEnd (from record one). Basically kind of a running total.

The hierarchy is:

1. Min as the lowest
2. ROP
3. Max

And lines in the output table are generated until `InventoryEnd` reaches either above or equal to MAX.

Anyone have a good idea to a select into statement for generating the output records?

Comment: Questions asking for programming help should show your attempt at solving the problem. This is not a code writing service.

Comment: A cursor is the way to go.